# accessing soap on iis from apache / php

Tags: php, apache, soap, windows-server-2008

I have to make a SoapClient in PHP for a webservice that is hosted on a Windows / IIS.
When I run the script from a local IIS + PHP, it works.
When I run the same script from a local XAMP of from an Apache webserver, I always get the same error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://online.wings.eu:8080/wsdl/IWingsWeb'

```
<?php
$url = 'https://online.wings.eu:8080/wsdl/IWingsWeb';

$options["connection_timeout"] = 25;
$options["location"] = $url;
$options['trace'] = 1;

$client = new SoapClient($url,$options);
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
?>
```

SOAP and openssl is enable on the Apache.
I can also access other services that are hosted on a non-Windows server.

Is this a problem of my Apache or is this a problem of the Windows server that hosts the SOAP server?

Comment: Can you download the wsdl file directly? (for example by using curl?)

Comment: Yes, but when I load the wsdl from a local file, I get another error when i use a function of the service: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in...

Comment: Have you downloaded it directly, or within PHP? Are you sure Apache has the right to download a page that is hosted on port 8080?

Comment: I downloaded the source in my browser. When you enter the url, you get the wsdl. I saved it on the webserver as a wsdl-file, where I can load it from in the script.

Comment: Then first make sure that you can do the same in PHP from your Apache.

Comment: With the local IIS, I can load the WSDL from the url. On my Apache (local and webserver) I can not load the WSDL from the url. When I put the WSdL-file local, I can load it and I can see the functions, but I can not use any function from it. So I think the connection between the IIS (where the service is hosted) and my Apache is not OK, but I don't know why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the connection between Apache and the IIS server can not be established. You should check the following:

- Are there any firewalls, anti-malware programs, etc. that might block the 8080 (outgoing, not incoming) port from your Apache server?
- Are there any SSL certificates or passwords (or both), that are needed to connect to the server. If yes, you should tell PHP to set the appropriate headers.
- You might want to replace the default SoapClient to something that uses curl directly. There you can set a few curl parameters, and check whether about the actual error.

Like this:

```
class SoapCurlWrapper extends SoapClient {
  protected function callCurl($url, $data, $action) {
     $handle   = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml", 'SOAPAction: "' . $action . '"'));
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
     $response = curl_exec($handle);
     if (empty($response)) {
       throw new SoapFault('CURL error: '.curl_error($handle),curl_errno($handle));
     }
     curl_close($handle);
     return $response;
   }

   public function __doRequest($request,$location,$action,$version,$one_way = 0) {
       return $this->callCurl($location, $request, $action);
   }
 }
```

Note that PHP's SOAP implementation won't use the above wrapper to download the WSDL files (you have to do it manually), but you can use it to the actual WS calls, and might actually find out why it fails.

And you can use the above mentioned class like any `SoapClient`, eg:

```
$oWS = new SoapCurlWrapper($location_of_wsdl_file,$parameters);
```

Comment: Check 1: I asked, but no answer yet.
Check 2: not needed I think, my ISS worked without anything.
Check 3: SoapCurlWrapper gives same fatal error... Couldn't load from...
When I use another service url I found on the net, it works, but not with the service I need.

Comment: As I've said the WSDL download part will not work, as the wrapper will not be used for that. But for the actual SOAP communication the wrapper will be used, where you can add other debugging commands to help find out where the error is.

Comment: Nice! New error: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [CURL error: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure] 35 We're getting a bit further. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: SSL handshake error. Try changing SSL version to 2, or remove that line completely. Also try to read about the new error you have received, like here: http://serverfault.com/questions/229972/error14094410ssl-routinesssl3-read-bytessslv3-alert-handshake-failure35 It might seem that you need a client certificate to connect, so you should check point no.2 again.

Comment: OK! I've set curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
and all is running fine! THANK YOU VERY MUCH for the SoapCurlWrapper and setting me on the right track !